# Unix time stamps and part of filename in file.zip

Tags: bash, shell

In bash I would like to extract part of filename and add unixtimestamps of that file example:

I've got file named
`auto0-20190210-013032-1726436102-de_mirage-servername.dem`

And I want to zip it to make name like this:
`dem-de_mirage-1549758632-1549759944.zip`

where:

`de_mirage` is that part that I want to extract from name because it changes in some files

`1549758632` is unix timestamp when the file was created

`1549759944` is unix timestamp when the file was last time modifed

I've got that function for zipping files:

```
for file in `find "$DIR" -mmin +1 -name '*.dem' -print`
do
    zip -j $file.zip $file
    echo "  `basename $file`"
    mv -ft "$OUT" "$file".zip 
done
```

Comment: It's often a bad idea to "force" commands (eg. `mv -f`). You haven't defined `$OUT` in the code provided. Your script shown will produce one zip file for every `.dem` file found. Is that what you want?

Comment: $OUT is defined as folder where it moves, but i forgot to write that.
Yes, It's that what I want.

Comment: Is the format of your .dem filename always: (letters and digits), hyphen, 8 digit date, hyphen, multi-digit timestamp, hyphen, stuff, ".dem" ?

Comment: Always (letters and digits), hyphen, 8 digit date, 6 digit time, multi-digit timestamp (i feel like it's not timestamp), hyphen, stuff, ".dem

Comment: yeah, unless they're in the future :)

Comment: definitely no hyphens in the first part before the date?

Comment: auto0 is hyphen, that i want to remove.
With my script i can only zip my file so it looks like:
`auto0-20190210-013032-1726436102-de_mirage-servername.dem.zip`
but i want to make it look like this: 
`dem-de_mirage-1549758632-1549759944.zip`

Comment: what output do you get if you run `find DEM -newerBB DEM` ? (replace `DEM` with an actual filename)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's amended version of your code.

Alternative ways to pull out the special part of the filename and to find the mtime/ctime are added in comments.

```
for file in `find "$DIR" -mmin +1 -name '*.dem' -print`
    do
        ## strip prefix - simple bash version may be too general
#       special=${file#*-*-*-*-}

        ## strip prefix - complicated but bad match is less likely
        special=$(echo "$file"|grep -Po '^.+?-\d{8}-\d{6}-\d+-\K.+(?=\.dem$)')

        ## remove trailing servername (assuming it doesn't contain hyphens)
#       special=${special%-*}

        ## remove trailing servername (assuming it is a fixed string)
        ## can be repeated to remove multiple different server names
        special=${special%-servername1}
        special=${special%-servername2}

        ## see "perldoc -f stat" for possible stat fields that can be used
        ## this example outputs 9:mtime and 10:ctime
#       mctime=$(perl -e 'printf "%d-%d",(stat $ARGV[0])[9,10]' "$file")

        ## see "man stat" for other timestamp options
        ## creation time (birthtime %W) may not be supported
        ## this example outputs mtime-ctime
        mctime=$(stat --printf='%Y-%Z' "$file")

        zipfile="dem-${special}-${mctime}.zip"

        zip -j "$zipfile" "$file"
        echo "  $(basename "$file")"
        mv -ft "$OUT" "$zipfile" 
    done
```

Comment: half sucess now it's named like this:
`de_mirage-servername-1549758632-1549759944.zip`
dem- is missing what is really important for me, and i want to remove servername
so i want it to look like that:
`dem-de_mirage-1549758632-1549759944.zip`

Comment: and can you reverse timestamps positions?

Comment: I've amended the code. See comments on how to change the timestamps

Comment: ./gotv_www.sh: line 39: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `}'
./gotv_www.sh: line 59: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: With script before it looks like 
`dem-de_mirage-____ACEGO.PL______PL_EU__MULTIMOD__CASUAL_MG_COURSE_SURF_DR_-1549752088-1549795108.zip`
and
`____ACEGO.PL______PL_EU__MULTIMOD__CASUAL_MG_COURSE_SURF_DR_` si that servername but i've got 2 servers connected to the script so i want to remove it

Comment: You have to edit my answer and customise it, particularly the section about stripping servernames

Comment: is it any way to remove server name llike auto0 ?

Edit:
`        ## remove trailing servername (assuming it doesn't contain hyphens)
       special=${special%-*}

        ## remove trailing servername (assuming it is a fixed string)
        ## can be repeated to remove multiple different server names
#        special=${special%-servername1}
#        special=${special%-servername2}
`
After that change, it works! Thank you.

Comment: I've found something. I've got working create date timestamp (from dem file), but I want to get last time modifed timestamp from dem file too? Can you do this?
Because if i run script it makes all look like this: `dem-de_mirage-createtimestamp-date when i run script timestamp.zip

Comment: see mctime lines of my script. Simplest way to get mtime is probably `stat --printf="%Y" file.dem`

Comment: Don't care about that, amazing work man, i will skip that big Thumb up for you!

Comment: the idea of the script is to compute the parts and store them in variables, then combine them to form the zip name (see the `zipfile=` line. It's up to you what parts you want to compute and how you want to combine them. You aren't limited to the ones I've provided :)

Comment: Okey, one more time thank you! You did amazing job :)